# Kivy isn't working. [CRITICAL] [Window ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, kivy

I've had this problem for about a week .Basically, I had this problem on pycharm but solved it easily, but now I can't use pycharm anmore than 0 minutes at a time (don't pay), so I tried with sublime and VScode, but now theproblem was back, the same exact code and the same exact problem as in the past. I've installed all the dependencies and probabally spent 6 hours trying to solve this problem today. Still nothing, VScode just gives always the same output:

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Utilizador\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-02-01_50.txt
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
    [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, 
    or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
    sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Impossível localizar o módulo especificado.
      File "C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
        mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
      File "C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
        from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
```

This is super anoying because I´ve tried EVERYTHING, probabally have been in 50 forums just today trying to solve this, still the same. I've installed it from the terminal, to the enviromnent, without enviromnent, from VScode, conda, literally all has been done.

This is the code:

```
        import kivy
        from kivy.app import App
        from kivy.uix.label import Label
        from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
        from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
        from kivy.uix.button import Button
        from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
        from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
```

[VScode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoaIH.png)

Seriouslly, if you could help me It would be awesome.
Thanks.

Comment: -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the folder "lib" for storing modules is placed directly in the project folder.

Usually, when we install a module using the [global python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment), it will be stored in: "`\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages`".

It is recommended that you use a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments). After the module is installed, it will be stored in the folder in the project: "`\.env\lib\site-packages`".

[image]

Update:

If it still doesn't work, please try to find the folder of the module "kivy" in this python environment and try to delete it, and then reinstall the module. This can avoid problems caused by file corruption or incompatibility.

[image]